# Running a function within a React expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So this is a question about an answer I accidentally stumbled across while learning React.

Take the following `Table` component:

```
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
     const {list, pattern, onDismiss} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="newDiv">
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Within the `<div>` element with a class of `newDiv` if I add the following expression it works absolutely fine:

```
        {
          list.filter(isSearched(pattern)).map(item => 
            <div key={item.objectID}>

            </div>
          )
        }
```

If I don't use the shorthand arrow function syntax, or use an ES5 function, like this (notice the additional `{` and `}`:

```
        {
          list.filter(isSearched(pattern)).map(item => {
            <div key={item.objectID}>

            </div>
          })
        }
```

it does not work. Is this an official React 'thing'? You can only use ES6 functions like `map` like this if you use the shorthand version of an arrow function?

Comment: Not sure that was actually that helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return:

```
return <div key={item.objectID}>
```

In a single line arrow function in ES6 the return happens and is not necessary to be specific, nor are the `{ }`

If you use the longhand version you must instruct the return

Comment: Cheers! I had myself muddled thinking I was looking for a React problem when I had temporarily just forgotten the arrow function syntax

Comment: I've marked this one as the accepted answer, just because it had slightly more information. All other answers were great though.

Answer (score 2):

With the `{ }` syntax there is no implicit return so in that case your map-callback doesn't produce anything.

```
    {
      list.filter(isSearched(pattern)).map(item => {
        return <div key={item.objectID}></div>
      })
    }
```

Try using a `return` statement.

Comment: Of course there isn't! So this was clearly a dumb mistake; I was looking for a React problem when I had just got myself muddled with the arrow function syntax temporarily.

Comment: @OmisNomis There are no *dumb mistakes*, only learning opportunities.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 1):

The arrow function returns its statement by default unless you add curly braces, then it expects a return statement.